# To add locations' name on top of the NDVI map in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, labeling, ndvi, select-by-location, resolution

I have visualized an NDVI map on GEE and added my plant specimens locations on top of that using the "asset" tab.

Now, I need to choose different locations inside and outside the city based on their NDVI index.

For that, I need to see the name of the locations!
So, I am wondering if there is any possibility that I can add the name of the locations behind the NDVI map on top or any other method that could lead me to this result.